# DB2 temp table session concurrent user issue

Tags: database, db2, db2-400, ibm-data-studio

We are working with an application in .net with DB2 as a database. I am using the temp table in my stored procedure. Sometimes it throws an error "table is in use".

```
Declare Global Temporary Table TRNDETAILS (USERID INT ,
Name VARCHAR ( 25 )) WITH REPLACE;
```

As per the below document, temp tables are specific to the session. Then why is showing "table is in use". How can resolve it?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html

Comment: Conflicting tag and weblink.  Is Db2-server running on i-Series or is it Db2-LUW on cloud ?    ALSO:  please state the *actual* error-code (or sqlstate) that you receive.

Comment: DB2 server running on i-Series.

Comment: What is the actual error-code (sqlcode) or sqlstate that you receive?

Comment: The Db2 for i manual says that they are specific to an "application process"   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzdgtt.htm

Comment: Will DB2 create a unique table for each user's session?

Comment: This is the error code which I am getting... SQL0913 Row or object *** in QTEMP type *FILE in use @mao

Comment: I suspect connection pooling is in use here, which would explain why the table appears to hang around. In theory 'with replace' should resolve this, but it sounds as if something that has the table open (and therefore locked) is hanging around in the pool job. Recreating the table will need an exclusive lock. Perhaps try just clearing the table if this exception arises, which would presumably leave you ready to proceed; if that doesn't work, have a look at the open files (i.e. tables/views) listed against the job, to see if that helps you work out what is hanging on to the table.

Answer (score 1):

SQL0913N is either a lock-timeout or a deadlock.

This might not be in your session table. Unless your .net app is multithreading SQL on a single connection.

Check DSPRCDLCK, WRKOBJLCK related tools. You need to track down the SQL-statement(s) that are conflicting, and take action dependent on the cause. Sometimes this involves changing the isolation level in your application.

Examine the Db2 for i diagnostics to get more information , i.e. whether it is a lock-timeout or a deadlock, and which connections are involved, and which objects are involved.

Answer (score 0):

QTEMP is unique for every job/connection...

I assume your app only creates the temporary table in one place and that creating the temporary table is one of the first things it does.

I also suspect that you're using connection pooling within .NET.

Thus the connection isn't actually being closed, it's left open in the connection pool.

Somewhere in your app, you're not properly disposing of a result set and/or committing changes to the temp table.  Thus leaving rows inside it locked when the connection is returned to the pool.

You probably should drop the temporary table before your app closes the connection and returns the connection to the pool.

That should prevent the error, but it'd be a good idea to track down the bug that's leaving the rows locked in the first place.